# How to find the other devices in ipod using bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am struggling with this problem for last 2 days.What I need to do is that i need to transfer data between iPhone and Android  I have gone through this link. Also I had success in that...

I am able to discover my iPhone in my Nokia device, and when I click "ADD" in Nokia a 6 digit number is sent to iPhone, and here problem starts. I don't know what to do next.

I am using private framework BluetoothManager. Please help me as I am not able to get any documentation on BluetoothManager.framework.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that the native iDevice bluetooth stack doesn't support sending data to anything other than an iDevice and you need an app for that on both ends.

I've never heard of being able to transfer from an iPod/Phone/Pad to any other device.